# Listing all IP address and Port of client

Tags: c#

I am new in socket programming in c#. I just want to implement a simple program of listing all the IP address and port of the client requesting in the server. I have this code, no error but the gui not appearing upon starting the project. I already allow it through firewall and still no luck. Please help me thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9999);

            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            socket.Bind(ip);
            socket.Listen(10);

            Socket client = socket.Accept();
            IPEndPoint newclient = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
            dataGridViewSelectedUsers.Rows.Add(Convert.ToString(newclient.Address), Convert.ToString(newclient.Port));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try the below code will list requested ip to your listening server

```
UdpClient udpServer = new UdpClient(11000);
while (true)
            {
              var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
              var data = udpServer.Receive(ref remoteEP); // listen on port 11000 
            //list received ip address 
               listbox.items.Add(remoteEP.Tostring);

}
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer but my question is, only to port 11000? what if the client uses port 8001 will it still include in the list?

Comment: the above port is for example , you can try your port

Comment: can you make it dynamically/automatically detects the port of client?